# Perché l'aggettivo "siccitoso" si usa tanto poco?

Tags: word-usage

Ho sentito descrivere al telegiornale l'inverno che stiamo vivendo come:

***[siccitoso](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/siccitoso.php)***: (agg.)

> - Che è soggetto a lunghi periodi di siccità.

- Il termine mi sembrava  insolito e controllando con [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=siccitoso&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csiccitoso%3B%2Cc0) ho visto che si tratta di un aggettivo in uso in particolare fino agli anni 50'/60'.

Dubito che non ci siano stati periodi di siccità negli ultimi cinquant'anni, per cui probabilmente l'aggettivo, per qualche motivo,  è stato sostituito da qualche altra espressione.

Cos'è successo a questo termine? Con quali espressioni è stato sostituito?

Comment: Interessante... Anche qui abbiamo un inverno di gran siccità.

Comment: Non so rispondere sulle espressioni alternative (immagino che si usino delle perifrasi), ma è fisiologico che certe parole si comincino a usare di meno, anche se il concetto continua a esistere. Lo testimonia indirettamente la periodica comparsa di iniziative e concorsi sulle “parole da salvare” e simili. Per esempio, questo di qualche anno fa della Zanichelli: http://premiodiscrittura.zanichelli.it/2009/ (a destra). Persone zotiche, situazioni uggiose, gli artefici di qualcosa, e più o meno tutto il resto esiste: è solo che si usano di meno quelle specifiche parole.

Comment: Non devi prendere ngram come oro colato, cmq una veloce scorsa a google porta un bel po di materiale tecnico. Di solito senti spesso "secco". Forse "siccitoso" è passato ad essere un termine più usato in ambienti tecnici come agraria e geologia?

Answer (score 2):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI18/01060.jpg), quello che accade all'aggettivo "siccitoso" è che è di uso letterario:

> **Siccitóso**, agg. (superl. *siccitosìssimo*). Letter. Che
> soffre di lunghi periodi di siccità; abitualmente arido e secco (un terreno, una regione). 
>     [...] 
>     **2.** Povero di precipitazioni (una stagione).
>     [...]

(Ci sono altre accezioni che non riporto.)

Sinonimi più comuni sarebbero "secco", "arido".